# What are the stages of compilation and runtime of a Java AOT program?

Tags: java, aot

Recently I was interested in Java AOT and tried to compile some simple programs with it.

As I see it works like this:

- JDK calls Graal compiler, which emits .so file
- In runtime .so file is supplied into JVM and executed after JVM is loaded.

It looks too brief. Can someone explain compilation and runtime stages in details?

Comment: Why do you think it has to be complicated?  I think that's more complicated than it even is supposed to be.

Comment: @louis-wasserman I like your family name. I think Graal VM is already complicated, but I didn't mentioned it directly. I just want more details if it is possible.